# Playing with fonts in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, layout, fonts

Recently installed new wordpress theme. The problem is, there are only following font options to choose.

[image]

But I want to set Arial as default font for all content.

Tried to change css file of theme. No success!

How can I change all fonts to arial or something that will support all utf-8 characters?

Comment: lets have a link to the site. CSS should work fine.

Comment: @Fresheyeball http://blog.pcand.me/

Comment: Your question is highly dependent on the theme you use (which you have not shared). Please make it's full code available otherwise it's hard to say.

Comment: @hakre Which code? Theme name is Esplanade 1.0.4

Comment: you can use `!important` to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this line of code to the last line of style.css in your theme directory.

```
body {font-family: "Arial" !important;}
```

Comment: Ok, it maybe will fix problem. But I want to know the proper way from inside wordpress. Can you pls explain?

Comment: you should change the font options of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

add !important you are just being cascaded over.

```
body {
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Arial" !important; 
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.62em;
}
```

Also you should include a fallback like this `"Arial", sans-serif !important`

Comment: Kidding, right? Which URL I've posted? http://pcand.me/ or http://blog.pcand.me ?? http://screencast.com/t/39jUKlEmnbbi

Comment: As I posted above it maybe will fix problem. But I want to know the proper way from inside wordpress. Can you pls explain, why am I getting only these combinations of fonts inside wp? How can I change or add new font combinations?

Comment: There is not a proper way from inside wordpress. If its not in your admin, its not there. If you want it in your admin, you will have to manually add the option with php.

Comment: This would involve editing whatever plugin or theme you are using.